# How can I calculate distances with points in a huge matrix, 70000 rows, 6 columns?

Tags: scikit-learn, scipy, sparse-matrix, metrics, pairwise-distance

the matrix is about 70000 rows, 6 columns, the first two columns are x, y coordinates, the last four columns do not participate in calculation...

the code is

`distances = sklearn.metrics.pairwise.pairwise_distances(polygon_centers[:, 0:2], metric='euclidean', n_jobs=1)`

the Pycharm report Memory Error......
How can I do this Euclidean distance calculation?

Comment: I have tried the 'cdist' function in scipy.spatial ,
the code is like : dis = distance.cdist(p_cs,p_cs,'euclidean')
but the pyCharm report Memory Error.......

Comment: So, you are looking to generate a 70000x70000 ndarray?

Comment: This distance matrix will eat up 40gb give or take a bit. Probably time to think about why you're doing a distance matrix (kNN?) and if you can get to your next step without keeping the entire matrix in memory at one time.

Comment: "So, you are looking to generate a 70000x70000 ndarray?", oh, the points x,y coordinates are a 70000 * 2 ndarray, the point to point distance matrix is a 70000 * 70000 matrix.

Comment: 40gb.......!!! you are right.

Comment: Perhaps there is such an operation to calculate the distance between tens of thousands of pixels in the remote sensing image segmentation algorithm? How did they do it, can't python language do the distance calculation of this kind of large matrix?